# Is there a term for the inverse of a fixed-point operator?

Tags: recursion, category-theory, fixed-point

When working with recursion it is often useful to find the least or greatest [fixed points](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_fixed_point) of a morphism, often using a [fixed-point combinator](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator). When working with [recursion schemes](https://jtobin.io/practical-recursion-schemes), the inverse operation — finding a morphism for which a value is a fixed point — is also very useful, in which case the operation is sometimes called parameterizing and its result sometimes called a pattern functor or base functor.

Is there a more general term for this inverse fixed-point operation or its resulting morphism?